# How can I take one spreadsheet and re-order all the rows based on the order of another spreadsheet with the same data?

Tags: python, excel, spreadsheet

I have two spreadsheets in Excel, full of data including UUIDs, Sequence IDs, etc... I have all that data in my main spreadsheet in the order I want, but my second spreadsheet has the same data (plus more) in a very different order. I want to write a *python* program to reorder the data in the second spreadsheet to the same order as the first, and then output that into a third new spreadsheet (leaving the second one intact).

For the purpose of this, lets call the spreadsheets 'MAIN', 'SECOND', and 'NEW'. And the specific data I want to use to to reorder things can be called 'UUIDs' in all sheets and take the form of something like 'h4g22gbu5w009'.

I guess the order of operations would be to import both spreadsheets, iterate through the first one and for each instance in that spreadsheet, I then iterate through the second one and when finding a match I put it in the new spreadsheet?

What do you think, thanks in advance!

So far I haven't got a lot done as I'm not really sure where to start. I kind of know what needs to happen, but I'm not sure about starting yet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.